# Errorwhen WriteObject from Server To Socket

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket, serializable, objectoutputstream

Some one help me this this exception when send object from server to client
it is NotSerializableException <<
and i try to solve the error and  implements the interface Serializable and same exception >> >>> >

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package test;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


/**
 *
 * @author Haz
 */
public class Server {

    boolean isRunning = true;
    public static final int Port = 500;
    public static final String Address = "127.0.0.1";
    ObjectOutputStream outToClient;
    Socket Client;
    ArrayList<ConnectionHandler> Handlers;
    HashSet<Socket> Callers;

    public Server() throws IOException {

        ServerSocket socketSer = new ServerSocket(500);
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);

        Handlers = new ArrayList<>();
        Callers = new HashSet<>();
        while (isRunning) {
             Client = socketSer.accept();
             System.out.println("Client Connect on Sever");
            ConnectionHandler handler = new ConnectionHandler(Client,socketSer);
            Handlers.add(handler);
            Callers.add(Client);
            SendConnectToAll(Handlers);


        }
    }


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        new Server();
    }

    private void SendConnectToAll(ArrayList<ConnectionHandler> Handlers){


        try {
            outToClient = new ObjectOutputStream(Client.getOutputStream());
            outToClient.writeObject(Handlers);
            outToClient.flush();
            outToClient.close();   
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


    }

}





/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Haz
 */
public class SocketClient {
    Socket Client;
    ObjectInputStream inputFromServer;

    public SocketClient(String Address,int Port) {
        try {
            Client = new Socket(Address,Port);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SocketClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                         Object temp =null;

                try {
                    inputFromServer = new ObjectInputStream(Client.getInputStream());
                    temp =inputFromServer.readObject();
                    while((temp)!=null){
                          temp = inputFromServer.readObject();
                        System.out.println(temp);
                    }
                    inputFromServer.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(SocketClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(SocketClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            }

        }).start();
    }



}
```

and class ConnectionHandler it is empty but i implements

```
public class ConnectionHandler implements Runnable,Serializable {

    private Socket Client;
    private ServerSocket Server;

    public ConnectionHandler(Socket Client, ServerSocket Server) {
        this.Client = Client;
        this.Server = Server;
    }
```

Comment: ConnectionHandler  does not seem to implement anything, does it even compile?

Comment: yes, i Create arraylist from connectionHandler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ConnectionHandler is not serializable because it contains references to Socket and ServerSocket, which are not serializable.  You would have to write your own serialization and deserialization methods to make it serializable.

However, it doesn't make sense to make it serializable anyway, since it doesn't have any serializable data in it to transmit over the network.